# Menue "create new mailing" leading to "old server" after creating test-server via backup of VM?

Tags: civimail

)
after setting up a staging-server-VM via snapshot of our "production server", i've got two very strange/mysterious effect:

- when choosing the menue-item "create new mailing" the form with the URL/domain of the original server is displayed !-( ( https://machmittestsrv....../crm/index.php?q=civicrm/mailing/send&reset=1 => https://machmit..../crm/index.php?q=civicrm/a/#/mailing/35 instead of https://machmittestsrv..../crm/index.php?q=civicrm/a/#/mailing/35)
  BUT: all the other menue-entries are leading to the domain/URL of the new staging-server..
- the top-menue is not there but on the left side only... At the top there is still the drupal7-menue-bar

Please try to explain how civicrm / drupal7 does the "translation" of the menue-URL .

Thanks a lot in advance ;-)

best regards
Dieter

Comment: have you tried civicrm/menu/rebuild ?

Comment: hi pettednz,
thanks for Your suggestion !-)
Performing this task is ending up with "..did everything ok.." -
unfortunately it does not change anything :-(

I'd like to know where to find the "link translation"... 
? is it in a DB-table / -record ?
or
as a symlink in a directory ?

Comment: hi pettednz,
thanks a lot for Your genial suggestion !-)
That's the solution of all the problems :-))))
=> it took some seconds to be on....

best regards & a nice weekend
Dieter

Comment: cool. if that was the solution, i have added as an Answer so pls Accept and +1 it. thx

Comment: hi pettednz, sorry for delayed answer & for the bad news:
The solution has been a "partial and temporrary improvement" only :-(

=> first, after "civicrm/menu/rebuild" the menue-link of "setup new mailing" lead to an empty page with an error-message like "not allowed"....
now, after system-restart, it's leading to the old-server's "setup new mailing" again :-(

Please try to explain how the forwarding (translation of the URL) is performed / implemented in ccivicrm.

I am afraid, i have to follow it step by step to find the place of the buggy translation.

thx & best regards
Dieter

Answer (score 1):

You may find the solution for this is to visit civicrm/menu/rebuild